# sed Mac terminal delete lines starting with a word but not ending with another word

Tags: bash, sed

I have the below txt files with the text (name of file Test.txt)

```
THE Lord is djncjdnjfn one almighty

THE Lord is dcdcdc great

THE Lord is dcdcdc one

THE Lord is cdcdcdc most powerful

THE Lord has cdcdcdc many faces

THE Lord is cdcdc above all
```

I want to delete all the lines which are starting with THE Lord and not ending in one
So output would be

```
THE Lord is dcdcdc one
```

I am using terminal and I am using the below command

```
sed -i "" '/^THE Lord*one$/!d' Test.txt
```

This is not working for me Moreover I have a few observations
if I want to delete all the lines starting with THE Lord

`sed -i "" '/^THE Lord/d' Test.sh` is not working

instead `sed -i "" '/THE Lord/d` is working

Similary if I want to delete lines ending with one

`sed -i "" '/one$/d' Test.sh` is not working

instead `sed -i "" '/one/d'` is working

I am not able to make use of `$ ^` anchors

Comment: Probably leave out the `-i ""` while experimenting, and observe the output you get on standard output.

Comment: The `*` will look for zero or more strings preceding it. You should use `.*`

Comment: I notice Anubhava has interpreted the question slightly differently than I have. Your examples don't really show what should happen to lines which do not begin with `THE Lord`. Your prose description suggests that they should be preserved.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit: You mustn't change your question in a way which invalidates existing answers. Probably (accept one of the answers you got here, or post one of your own and accept that, and) ask a new question with your _actual_ requirements.

Comment: ok i'll do that I was asked to edit the question anyways il post another

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68207568/sed-mac-terminal-delete-lines-starting-with-a-substring-but-not-ending-with-anot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` is a scripting language. There is support for simple if/then logic by way of branching.  The `b` command skips to the end of the script and causes `sed` to abandon further processing of the current line.

```sh
sed -e '/^THE Lord/!b' -e '/one$/!d' file
```

The `!` negation operator says to run the command if the previous condition is false.

Add the `-i ""` option to write the changes back to the file instead of displaying the results on standard output.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider this `sed`:

```sh
sed -n '/^THE Lord /{ /one$/p; }' file

THE Lord is dcdcdc one
```

You may consider this *simpler* `grep` solution as well:

```sh
grep "^THE Lord .* one$" file

THE Lord is dcdcdc one
```

Comment: When all lines start with `THE` you can `grep -o "The.*one"`. I think `Another line` should be found too.

Comment: Indeed `grep "^THE Lord .* one$" file` would also work

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The sed command is not giving any output however the grep is working fine
I tried to use this as a base and applied the same to other file which has content like this 
install_resource "${PODS_ROOT}/darwin-umt-ios/jarvis-umt-ios/Classes/ViewController/IfscStoryBoard.storyboard"
install_resource "${PODS_ROOT}/utm-iOS/Resources.bundle"

I want to only keep 
install_resource "${PODS_ROOT}/utm-iOS/Resources.bundle"
and delete al the lines which are starting with install_resource "${PODS_ROOT} but not ending with /Resources.bundle

Comment: Meanwhile you may try: `sed '/^install_resource ${PODS_ROOT}/{ /Resources\.bundle$/!d; }' file`

Comment: this is not working sed '/^install_resource ${PODS_ROOT}/{ /Resources\.bundle$/!d; }' file

Answer (score 0):

An awk:

```
$ awk '$1=="THE" && $2=="Lord" && $NF=="one"' file
```

Output:

```
THE Lord is dcdcdc one
```

`$1` is the first word, `$NF` is the last. *delete lines - - not ending with another word* is the same as *output lines ending with a word*.